# JQuery: how to check a radio button?

Tags: jquery, radio-button

So if this qstring var is set then i need to check a certain radio button

ive tried the following :

```
$("#AcctRB").attr('checked', 'checked');
$('input[id=AcctRB]:eq(1)').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

which does not work.  I might have a syntax error

Here is the rb  :

```
<input type="radio" onclick="accountShow()" id="AcctRB" runat="server" name="GuestAndAccountRB" enableviewstate="true" />Account


 <% If Request.QueryString("login") = "guest" Then%> 
                 <script type= "text/javascript">
                     $(".new-accnt-ad").show("slow");
                     $(".accountPanel").hide("slow");
                     $(".guestPanel").show("slow");
                     $("#AcctRB").attr('checked', 'checked');
                 </script>
                 <%Else%>
              <script type= "text/javascript">
                  $(".new-accnt-ad").hide("slow");
                  $(".accountPanel").show("slow");
                  $(".guestPanel").hide("slow");
                  $('input[id=AcctRB]:eq(1)').attr('checked', 'checked');
              </script>

                 <% End If %>
```

This simply does not check the radio button in either case ive tried.

Comment: Is this the real code? Is the element rendering before the script? Isn't this wrong `If Request.QueryString("login") = "guest" Then`? Shouldn't it be `==`? Does any script tag get rendered?

Comment: My answer was going to be the same as Alec. I think your javascript is firing at the wrong time. You're code works after the page is loaded. Are you using firebug (a firefox add-on). You can put `console.log($("#AcctRB"))` in your code right before you check it to make sure the element is loaded as the script fires.

Comment: It would be useful to see the generated markup instead of the ASP code. It's hard to tell what radio buttons are actually on the page and with what IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JS might run before all the elements are created. Check out: [$(document).ready()](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
});
```

It's also not necessary to do this with JavaScript; simply add it to the HTML directly, depending on the `QueryString("login")`.

Comment: hmm can you please demonstrate?

Comment: `<input <% If Request.QueryString("login") == "guest" %> checked="checked" <% End If %> />`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[id=AcctRB]:eq(1)').attr('checked', true);
```

Comment: While this is "better", it should work fine with _"checked"_ as the attr value.

Answer (score 1):

I would bet that your selectors are not returning any elements, because that should work.  Although it's probably cleaner to set checked to `true` in `attr()`.

Proof this works: http://jsfiddle.net/A7Bke/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Squeegy. I had the same problem the other day, and the issue was that even though the selector seemed to be correct, it was not retrieving any results.

I recommend getting a more advanced browser toolkit such as the [FireBug plugin for Firefox](http://www.getfirebug.com/) or using Chrome's Developer tools. Try your jQuery selectors out in the Console Window they provide, and see if the results are what you expect. These tools also allow you to place breakpoints in your JavaScript code to see if the selector is being called by the browser.

**Update:**
To test out jQuery selectors in Firebug, enable the Console tab, then simply type out the selector. The console will respond back with those elements that were selected by the jQuery call.

Comment: I have firebug, but i dont see where i can test my jquery